# splitting the data frame based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe called df. There are 20 rows and 2 variables test_value and day. 
I would like to create a new variable called test_x_max. It will capture the maximum value from the previous x records. Ex: if we assume X is 5 then if we are looking at row 15 ,  it needs to pick the maximum test_value  between day 10 to day 15. How can i achieve this ? 
Thanks in Advance.
Pavan

Comment: How do you correlate x=5 with row 15 to 10? Is it start from (max days - 5) which is 15 to (start - 5), which is 10?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including sample input and expected output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions Check out [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollmax` combined with `cummax`:

```
library(zoo)

df$test_x_max <- c(cummax(df$test_value[1:4]), rollmax(df$test_value, 5, align = "right"))
```

For example:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(day = 1:20, test_value = sample(20))
df$test_x_max <- c(cummax(df$test_value[1:4]), rollmax(df$test_value, 5, align = "right"))
df
#>    day test_value test_x_max
#> 1    1         10         10
#> 2    2          6         10
#> 3    3         16         16
#> 4    4         14         16
#> 5    5         12         16
#> 6    6          7         16
#> 7    7         19         19
#> 8    8         17         19
#> 9    9          4         19
#> 10  10         15         19
#> 11  11         13         19
#> 12  12          2         17
#> 13  13         11         15
#> 14  14          8         15
#> 15  15          3         13
#> 16  16          9         11
#> 17  17          1         11
#> 18  18         20         20
#> 19  19         18         20
#> 20  20          5         20
```

Answer (score 0):

Newish package called `slider` seems appropriate if you like `tidyverse` style

```r
library(dplyr)
library(slider)

set.seed(2020)

pretend_df <- tibble(
day = 1:20,
testvalue = sample(100, 20)
)

# if you MUST have 5 days worth
slide_dbl(pretend_df, ~ max(.x$testvalue), .before = 5, .complete = TRUE)
#>  [1] NA NA NA NA NA 88 88 88 88 70 70 72 93 93 93 93 93 93 80 82

# if you want to accept less than 5 days worth
slide_dbl(pretend_df, ~ max(.x$testvalue), .before = 5, .complete = FALSE)
#>  [1] 28 87 87 88 88 88 88 88 88 70 70 72 93 93 93 93 93 93 80 82

pretend_df$maxlast5 <- slide_dbl(pretend_df, ~ max(.x$testvalue), .before = 5, .complete = TRUE)

> pretend_df
# A tibble: 20 x 3
     day testvalue maxlast5
   <int>     <int>    <dbl>
 1     1        28       NA
 2     2        87       NA
 3     3        22       NA
 4     4        88       NA
 5     5        65       NA
 6     6        17       88
 7     7        36       88
 8     8        42       88
 9     9        70       88
10    10        49       70
11    11        56       70
12    12        72       72
13    13        93       93
14    14        80       93
15    15        29       93
16    16         3       93
17    17        66       93
18    18         4       93
19    19        78       80
20    20        82       82
```